# Mac Os control panel application

Tags: xcode, control-panel

I want to create application, which will run in MacOs control panel.

Help me please to find information about how to do this.

Comment: I think you should start by looking at the Mac OS X developer pages and then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer very helpful for me and another users who learn  this post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Preference Pane Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/PreferencePanes.html).

Comment: Thanks it is that what I searched !